# Perl built in exit and print in one command

Tags: perl, exit, die

I know I can die but that prints out the script name and line number.

I like to do things like `die 'error' if $problem;`

Is there a way to do that without printing line number stuff?

It would be nice not to have to use braces `if($problem){print 'error';exit}`

Comment: also print prints to STDOUT; die prints to STDERR

Comment: Oh. I just realized that while that does not matter now, it will matter later. Thanks. @ysth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the fairly natural-sounding:

```
print "I'm going to exit now!\n" and exit if $condition;
```

If you have perl 5.10 or above and add e.g. `use 5.010;` to the top of your script, you can also use `say`, to avoid having to add the newline yourself:

```
say "I'm going to exit now!" and exit if $condition;
```

Comment: Note that in the unlikely event that print fails, the program will not exit.  Better to say "print(...), exit if $condition;".

Comment: @Sean note that the parentheses after `print` in that example are required, otherwise it will exit without printing anything.

Answer (score 24):

Adding a newline to the [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) error message suppresses the added line number/scriptname verbage:

```
die "Error\n"
```

Answer (score 19):

You can append a new line to the die string to prevent perl from adding the line number and file name:

```
die "oh no!\n" if condition;
```

Or write a function:

```
sub bail_out {print @_, "\n"; exit}

bail_out 'oh no!' if condition;
```

Also keep in mind that `die` prints to stderr while `print` defaults to stdout.

Comment: Looks like I will have to write my own function because it will have to write to stdout. (I know that I did not originally state this, but I just realized that the only times I want to avoid the line number is when it prints to stdout).

Comment: @George: you can still use {{die}}

Answer (score 1):

*Here is an answer to the question you completed in you comment to Eric.*

To do both (print STDOUT and print without line number) you can still use `die` by changing the `__DIE__` handler:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { print @_, "\n"; exit 255 };

die "error" if $problem;
```

Answer (score -4):

You can create complex messages with `sprintf`:

```
die sprintf( ... ) if $problem;
```

Comment: You may want to click the `[delete]` link on this answer.